# Comparing Multiple Columns to Multiple lists and writing the matches to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have four lists of standard values that I would to compare to a corresponding column.

**Here are the four lists:**

```
industry_US=['Automotive', 'Retail', 'Gas', 'Other']

industry_EU=['Real Estate', 'Transport', 'Mining']

systype= ['Access', 'Video System']

accttype=['Commercial','Reseller','Small']
```

**Here is my Dataframe:**

```
data= [['Automotive','Education','Enterance','Commercial'],['Gas','Hotels','Access',' '],['Healthcare'," " ,'Video System','Reseller']]
df_test=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Industry_US','Industry_EU','System Type','Account Type'])
```

**Here is my desired output**

```
{
'Filename' : {error found in 'System Type', 'The value entered in System Type is not a standard value'}
}
```

This is what I have so far for this process but I am not sure how to write everything to a double nested dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

dict= {'file name': {'error':'description of the error'}}

data= [['Automotive','Education','Enterance','Commercial'],['Gas','Hotels','Access',' '],['Healthcare'," " ,'Video System','Reseller']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Industry_US','Industry_EU','System Type','Account Type'])

industry_US=['Automotive', 'Retail', 'Gas', 'Other']

industry_EU=['Real Estate', 'Transport', 'Mining']

systype= ['Access', 'Video System']

accttype=['Commercial','Reseller','Small']

col_list=['industry_US','industry_EU','systype', 'accttype']

if col_list.isin df:
    return None
else:
    dict.update({col_list : 'the value entered does not match the standard values'})
```

I would like to compare these four columns to the four list using a function to keep the code as efficient as possible. If the values in the columns match the value in the list nothing needs to happen but if the values don't match put the non-matching values in a nested dictionary. I am not concerned about the NaN values so those can stay out of the dictionary.

With the code I have I get errors like AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin' Any suggestion on how to efficiently compare multiple lists to multiple df columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand which output you want, but you can easily get the list of invalid values with:

```
valid = {'Industry_US': ['Automotive', 'Retail', 'Gas', 'Other'],
         'Industry_EU': ['Real Estate', 'Transport', 'Mining'],
         'System Type': ['Access', 'Video System'],
         'Account Type': ['Commercial', 'Reseller', 'Small']}

mask = df_test.apply(lambda c: c.isin(valid[c.name]))
df_test.mask(mask|df_test.eq(' ')).stack()
```

output:

```
0  Industry_EU     Education
   System Type     Enterance
1  Industry_EU        Hotels
2  Industry_US    Healthcare
dtype: object
```

##### displaying an error message:

```
for i, v in df_test.mask(mask|df_test.eq(' ')).stack().iteritems():
    print(f'error found in row "{i[0]}", column "{i[1]}": "{v}" is invalid')
```

output:

```
error found in row "0", column "Industry_EU": "Education" is invalid
error found in row "0", column "System Type": "Enterance" is invalid
error found in row "1", column "Industry_EU": "Hotels" is invalid
error found in row "2", column "Industry_US": "Healthcare" is invalid
```